# Clean way to convert CURL to Jquery/Javascript [Instagram]

Tags: jquery, ajax, curl, instagram

I'm trying to convert the curl command from the instagram api to jquery(ajax/get).

```js
 curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
    -F 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' \
    -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
    -F 'redirect_uri=AUTHORIZATION_REDIRECT_URI' \
    -F 'code=CODE' \
    https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

*From the doc :*

> "In order to make this exchange, you simply have to POST this code,
>   along with some app identification parameters"

```js
var clientId = "my client id";
var clientSecret = "my client secret";
var redirectURI = "http://localhost:3000/instagram";
var myCode = "my instagram code";
var uri = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=' + clientId + '&client_secret=' + clientSecret + '&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=' + redirectURI + '&code=' + myCode;
var url = encodeURIComponent(uri);

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "json",
   url: '  https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=' + clientId + '&client_secret=' + clientSecret + '&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=' + redirectURI + '&code=' + myCode,
   success: function (result) {
      console.log(result);
   }
});
```

Doesn't seems to work for me...

Getting Cross Origin Block Request [CORS] error.

Comment: interesting error you have in the browser console **Doesn't seems to work for me**

Comment: Getting Cross Origin Block Request [CORS] error ^^

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in order to send values in the query string, use the `.data` property of the options object you send to [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). And if you want to create the url programatically, do not forget to URL encode the values you send via [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Try with jsonp. Something like:

```
function myinstagramfunction (json_object)
{
    // I fetch here the json object that contains the info of all the pictures returned
    console.log("OK");
}
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   dataType: "jsonp",
   url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/YOUR_HASHTAG/media/recent?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE&callback=myinstagramfunction',
   success: function (result) {
      console.log(result);
   }
});
```